# PC Using LLVMPIPE Instead of NVIDIA GPU

Tags: nvidia, gpu-driver

I recently built a server PC for a friend's website and their GPU shows up as LLVMPIPE.
[image: LLVMPIPE]

The nvidia drivers are already installed but its not showing up in the settings.[image]

I am trying to get it to use the gpu drivers so I am not limited to using 256mb of video memory.
inxi -Gx:
[image]

Please help me fix this issue as my friend needs to use his GPU for mining.

lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display' output:

[image]

[![enter image description here][5]][5]

Comment: What is the point of using Nvidia in a server? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: @Pilot6 My friend will be using his GPU for mining and some other things.

Comment: PLEASE don't post screenshots of text. The `nvidia` driver is not installed. Disable Secure Boot in BIOS and run `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-510`. Post output if there are some errors.

Comment: @Pilot6 it's already installed though ```The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-modules-nvidia-510-5.15.0-25-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-modules-nvidia-510-5.15.0-40-generic
``` Edit: Secure boot is already disabled and reinstalling the drivers didn't change anything

Comment: Did you reboot after that?

Comment: @Pilot6 Do I need to restart to see the changes? I'm a linux newbie,

Comment: @Pilot6 nvm im rebooting

Comment: Yes, you need to reboot after you installed the drivers.

Comment: @Pilot6 Damn it worked! Never knew the solution was this simple. Make an answer and I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reboot after you install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Thanks again for helping me!